# Question about passive in a process

Tags: passive-voice

A questions from a student. In the sentence "the plant operaties 24r hours a day", why is this not in the passive as the plant can not operate itself?

Comment: It's perfectly normal to say a *device / system / etc.* ***operates*** in some particular way, just as we can say *The pub **opens** at 7 o'clock.* The subject of such verbs doesn't *have* to be capable of "volitional" acts.

Comment: _Operate,_ like most English action verbs, can be used either transitively (_The city operates the power station_), with an agent subject and a patient object, or intransitively, with a patient subject and no object (_The power station operates 24 hours a day_). This is the intransitive usage. Only transitive sentences can have a passive form.

Comment: Compare with 'the painting sold – eventually' and 'he sold the painting'. Different but related usages. The passive 'The painting was sold – eventually' is also available. 'She sold the painting' is the transitive usage, while 'The painting sold' is sometimes called the middle usage. It is available for fewer verbs than the passive.